# how to darken the whole page behind a popup?

Tags: html, django, popup, sidebar

> I have this sidebar that I want to make the whole background dark when it is clicked on I used this code but the posts remain white also the dark background does not get closed when I close the sidebar what should I do?? I post the html here please tell me if I need to post other pages

[image: it looks like this]

Thanks in advance

my post.html

```html
<script>
  function openModal() {
  $("#overlay").css({"display":"block"});
  $("#modal").css({"display":"block"});
}
</script>

<style>
  #modal {
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  border:solid 1px #000;
  display:none;
  background-color:#fff;
}

#overlay {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display:none;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0.5;
}
</style>


<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="modal"></div>








<div class="container">
    <div style="margin-top: 25px"></div>
    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{post.title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        {{ post.body|truncatewords_html:30 }}
        <hr>
        <p><img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}" width="75" height="75"> Author: {{ post.author }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'detail' post.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-small" >Read More <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-three-dots" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M3 9.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3zm5 0a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 3z"/>
          </svg></a>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" id="deleteButton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-trash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M5.5 5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 6v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm2.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5Zm3 .5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v6a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0V6Z"/>
            <path d="M14.5 3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H13v9a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h-.5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1H6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h2a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h3.5a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v1ZM4.118 4 4 4.059V13a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4.059L11.882 4H4.118ZM2.5 3h11V2h-11v1Z"/>
          </svg></a>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Delete Confirmation Modal</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <div class="icon-box">
          </div>                
          <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>    
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p  class="text-muted">Do you really want to delete these records? This process cannot be undone.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' post.id %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>     
  </body>
  </html>
</div>
```

the html my sidebar is in

```html
{% load static %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'website/icons8-reading-unicorn-48.png'%}" alt="My image" width="75"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'new' %}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> New Post</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}"><i class="fa fa-book" ></i> Genres</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href ="https://github.com/Jasmine-dy"><i class="fa fa-github" style="margin-right: 10px"></i></a>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <a class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" href="{% url 'profile' %}" style="margin-right: 15px"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M3 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H3Zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6Z"/>
          </svg> {{ user.username }}</a>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" href="{% url 'logout' %}" style="margin-right: 15px">Logout</a>
        {% else %}
          <a class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" href="{% url 'signup' %}" style="margin-right: 15px">Sign up</a>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" href="{% url 'login' %}"  style="margin-right: 15px">Sign In</a>
        {% endif %}

        <style>
          #right{
            position: absolute;
            top: relative;
            left: 1026px;
          }
        </style>
        
        <style>
          #side{
            position: relative;
            top: relative;
            left: 690px;
          }
        </style>

            <div id="side">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-light" class="border-0" class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">
                  <img onclick="openModal()" src="{% static 'website/icons8-menu-24 (1)ggg.png'%}" alt="buttonpng"/>
              </button>  
            </div>
      
        
        <div id="right">
         <form id="srchbr" class="d-flex" role="search" action="{% url 'search-view' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" style="margin-right: 3px" name="search_query" required aria-label="Search">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-light" class="border-0">
              <img src="{% static 'website/icons8-search-24ggg.png'%}" alt="buttonpng"/>
            </button>   
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</nav>


<div>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
  }
  
  .sidebar a {
      padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #747474;
      display: block;
      transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .sidebar a:hover {
      color: #222222;
  }
  
  .sidebar .closebtn {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 25px;
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  .openbtn {
      font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #747474;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      border: none;
  }
  
  .openbtn:hover {
      background-color: #444;
  }
  
  #main {
      transition: margin-left .5s;
      padding: 16px;
  }
  
  /* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
  @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>


  
  
  <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Genres</a>
      <a href="https://github.com/Jasmine-dy">Contact</a>
      <a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Your Account</a>
  </div>
  
  
  <style>
      #menuu{
        position: relative;
        top: relative;
        left: 698px;
      }
    </style>
  
  
  <script>
  function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
      document.getElementById("menuu").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  }
  
  function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("menuu").style.marginLeft= "0";
  }
  </script>
  
  </body>
  </html> 
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the [::backdrop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::backdrop) pseudo -element

Answer (score 2):

A very basic example of using the `::backdrop` css property to darken behind a popup / dialog.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  document.querySelector('dialog').showModal()
});
document.querySelector('dialog').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  e.target.close()
});
```

```css
::backdrop{
  background:black
}
dialog[open]{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<dialog>Hello World! Click me to close me</dialog>
<button>popup</button>
```